# Omitting the pronoun and the verb after “when”

Tags: grammar

In a court hearing, the prosecution is asking a witness about the incident they witnessed:

> *Prosecution:* there is a point in time when a customer in there [in the store] goes outside, is that correct?
> *Witness:* yes.
> *Prosecution:* alright, and was that cusomer a male or a female?
> *Witness:* er, **when customer**, you mean the woman that came out of the store?

The only case of omitting the pronoun and the verb that I am familiar with is the case of *when* proceeding an adjective.
Does using a noun after *when* seem correct?

Comment: It isn’t correct. The witness was probably nervous testifying and got her words mixed up.

Comment: @StephenS Really interesting answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: What she *meant* to say was *Er,... **when you say** "customer", [do] you mean the woman...*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Yes. Actually I thought that "you say" was intentionally omitted and there was a pattern that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, the witness was probably nervous, and "misspoke". What she actually comes out with is a "mash-up" of two perfectly valid constructions...

> 1: *Er,... when **you say** "customer", [do] you mean the woman...?*
> 2: *Er,... **by** "customer", [do] you mean the woman...?*

I see no reason to favour one over the other there, and the choice makes absolutely no difference to the meaning. It has to *be* one or the other, though; it can't be both.